# How can I plot a tensor?

Tags: python, matplotlib, torch, tensor

I have to plot a torch tensor of dimension [9,224,224].
Is there a method with matplotlib.pyplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can plot images

Matrices are easily plotted as images. Then if you have higher dimensions, each of them can be broken down into some number of matrices.

```
a = np.random.random((9, 224, 224)).reshape((3, 3, 224, 224))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3)

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        ax[i][j].imshow(a[i][j])
```

It's worth considering if this is appropriate for the data in question, but given a suitable configuration, it can work very well. For example viewing weights of a neural network.

Comment: No, the tensor is representative of an image of 9 channels

Comment: @GiuseppePuglisi Well, an image for each channel sounds very appropriate. Or even three RGB images if you like.